# How to run AWS `amplify init` in an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, aws-amplify-cli

I am automating the creation of my Angular/Amplify project using Ansible. I am stuck on running `amplify init` in Ansible. `amplify init` requires the use of the up arrow and down arrow keys to navigate its menus.

I can use Ansible `expect` to accept defaults and specify a literal string for some answers, but the arrow keys are required to specify things like the profile.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Amplify headless mode](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/headless) allows you to specify `amplify init` arguments as string literals without navigating menus using arrow keys. I use the `--amplify` argument to specify the environment, and `--providers` to specify the Amplify administrator profile. `--yes` means to accept the defaults for everything else.

Here is my play that runs `amplify init`. It presumes that you have already created your Angular (or other framework) project. It depends on predefined variables `amplify_project_dir` and `amplify_project_administrator_profile`:

```yaml
- name: Initialize Amplify for this project
  command:
    chdir: "{{ amplify_project_dir }}"
    cmd: >
      amplify init
        --yes
        --amplify
          {\"envName\":\"dev\"}
        --providers
          {\"useProfile\":true,\"profileName\":\"{{ amplify_project_administrator_profile }}\"}
    creates: "{{ amplify_project_dir }}/amplify/"
```

The JSON argument values must contain no unescaped whitespace. Jinja2 eliminates the whitespace in `{{ amplify_project_administrator_profile }}`.